# Code::Blocks: how to get block lines

Tags: codeblocks

i have scoured the internet and this site for an answer, but haven found one yet.

Do you know of any plugins for Code::Blocks that enable block lines(those things that go from curly brace to curly brace when indenting your code)?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

EDIT: i probably should have added a picture of what i meant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqhsH.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Show indentation guides" under Editor Options.

Indendation guides are not precisely what you describe (that's rather computerfreaker's answer), but they are what you show in that picture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to these:

[image]

If that's the case, go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Folding`, and make sure you check `Enable folding`. Hit `OK` and Code::Blocks will refresh your code windows, adding those folding blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Plug-ins->Source Code Formatter (AStyle) (for codeblocks editor)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it seems that this is only a code beautifier, i meant this : http://imgur.com/rtvQOGC

Comment: Oh understand now. Look this http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html

Comment: looks like there's no mention of how to do this :/ thanks anyway!